# Symfony does not redirect to login route after session is expired

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I am using Symfony 3.1 and angularjs. I would like to redirect the users to a login page when the session expires. However, when I delete a session and click on one of the ng-click button in my view, symfony actually redirects to the loginAction in LogInController. However, it does not render the login page.

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
  {
    error_log('Here in login');

    // get access to authentication utilities
    $authenticationUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

    // get the login error if there is one
    $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

    // render login.html.twig
    return $this->render(
        'security/login.html.twig',
        array(
            // last username entered by the user
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error'         => $error,
        )
    );

}
```

[This is the network tab after clicking the ng-click button after deleting the session.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBrm9.png)

Comment: what does it render?

Comment: It renders the previous view.

Comment: so the controller isn't executed

Comment: It executes the controller. It logs the above error log statement. It also gives the appropriate response in the developer tools' network tab. However, it does not change the view in the browser. I have uploaded an image which has the response of the login action. Please see the updated question.